# get date between start date to end date in php month wise count

Tags: php, mysql, date

In php how to slite month wise count each user in following data

```
SELECT * FROM sales_info WHERE assigned_dse_name IN ('ANBHAZHAGAN .') AND invoice_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 23:59:59'
```

in want to take count has

```
 month   count
  01      0
  02      0
  03      5
  04      3
  05      7
  06      4
```

how to use query using split up month wise loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT `mouth`, sum(`count`) AS `count` 
FROM (
    SELECT LPAD(MONTH(invoice_date), 2, '0') AS `month`, COUNT(1) as `count`
    FROM sales_info
    WHERE assigned_dse_name IN ('ANBHAZHAGAN .') AND invoice_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY MONTH(invoice_date)
    UNION
    SELECT LPAD(t.`month`, 2, '0') AS `month`, t.`count` FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 2 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 3 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 4 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 5 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 6 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 7 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 8 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 9 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 10 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 11 AS `month`, 0 AS `count` UNION
        SELECT 12 AS `month`, 0 AS `count`) t
    WHERE t.`month` >= MONTH('2016-01-01 00:00:00') AND t.`month` <= MONTH('2016-06-01 23:59:59'))TMP
GROUP BY `month`
ORDER BY `month`
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(invoice_date) AS month,
    COUNT(*) as count 
FROM sales_info 
WHERE
    assigned_dse_name IN ('ANBHAZHAGAN .') AND
    invoice_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY MONTH(invoice_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month,count(*)
FROM sales_info 
WHERE assigned_dse_name IN ('ANBHAZHAGAN') AND invoice_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 23:59:59'
group by month
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check Below Link for Your Answer

**[Click here for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW9px.png)**
 SELECT MONTH(invoice_date) as Month_no,count(*) as Count
    FROM sales_info 
    WHERE assigned_dse_name IN ('ANBHAZHAGAN .') AND invoice_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 23:59:59' group by MONTH(invoice_date)